# PHP Find the closet date to a given day that doesn't matches any date in an array

Tags: php, arrays, date

I would like to show the closest availabilty to the users from their choosen date if that date is unavailable.

The unavailable dates are stored in an array like this:

```
Array([0]->2020-07-06, [1]->2020-07-07, [2]->2020-07-08, [3]->2020-07-11)
```

As you can see what mekes is a little more difficult that there are two available dates between [2] and [3]

And lets say the user choose `2020-07-06` than I would like to show `2020-07-09`

Currently I do a simple `asort()` on the array and show the last day with `end()` but this is obivously not ok because I skip two days.

How can I show closest available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to implement this is to check whether the requested date is in the array, and if so, increment it by a day until you find a date which isn't in the array:

```
$unavailable = array('2020-07-06', '2020-07-07', '2020-07-08', '2020-07-11');

$requested = new DateTime('2020-07-06');
while (in_array($requested->format('Y-m-d'), $unavailable)) {
    $requested->modify('+1 day');
}
echo $requested->format('Y-m-d');
```

Output:

```
2020-07-09
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/F4D8b)